# iPhone - NSNumberFormatter problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I am using NSNumberFormatter to create a currency formatted string.
Everything works fine on most devices, but on some devices for example devices with Korean language, the $ sign shows up as a rectangle.

```
NSNumberFormatter *currencyStyle = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[currencyStyle setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[currencyStyle setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSNumber *amount = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:moneyAmount];
NSString *amountString =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [currencyStyle stringFromNumber:amount]];
[currencyStyle release];
```

Any way to fix this problem?

Rhanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175963/uilabel-irr-krw-and-khr-currencies-with-wrong-symbol ?

Comment: very similar but not a duplicate. that guy is having problem with non English and non ASCII characters. I am having this problem with a simple $ sign, which is supported by any font available, or let's say supported by the font i am using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your comment in the question, it sounds like you just want the `$` currency symbol, regardless of whatever the defined currency symbol is for the user's current locale.

This is done using the `-setCurrencySymbol:` instance method of the `NSNumberFormatter` class. In your case, you could do the following:

```
[currencyStyle setCurrencySymbol:@"$"];
```

Comment: wow so it was actually trying to display Korean currency? Interesting, thanks