# UTF8 iPhone can't read amharic letters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, utf-8

It has suddenly happened that I need to output a couple of strings in amharic (ethiopian) and some quite exotic (I think tamil if in Cambodia they use it). I store these strings in DB and they look fine -> (ሳንቲም).

After retrieving them from db with:

```
currObj.originalUnitName=(originalUnitName)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:originalUnitName]:@"";
```

I am getting in device nice squares only which imho means iPhone has no proper decoder. Is there any solution for this case?

P.S I am using iOS 5.1

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What symbol are you trying to use?  are you properly escaping your strings if they are unicode.

Comment: What font are you using to output the NSString? There's number of fonts in iOS without a proper UTF8 support. (e.g. Helvetica Neue) I suggest you to perform further tests with standard Helvetica, which is (almost) fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What font are you using to output the NSString?
There's number of fonts in iOS without a proper UTF8 support. (e.g. Helvetica Neue)
I suggest you to perform further tests with standard Helvetica, which is (almost) fine.

Comment: This should be a comment IMHO.

Comment: Agreed, but I'm not allowed to comment on the question.

Comment: Nathan: Then I'm afraid there's no easy answer to that. I was facing similar issue more than 2 years ago - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175963/uilabel-irr-krw-and-khr-currencies-with-wrong-symbol . There's no solution up to date. Apple didn't react to the opened bug report at all.

Comment: @serb there's no problem with ₩ signs and etc... there's only ethiopian letters issue.... anyway. Looks like that I've googled this issue and haven't fond any clear answer. Dammit these letters...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use special font that provides these characters. "Abyssinica SIL" (http://software.sil.org/abyssinica/download/) worked in my case.